# Add 5 Business Days to a timestamp

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following code which we have used to note the start date of projects. We have found it to be less than useful. I would like to change this to a due date by adding 5 business days to the current date.

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  var time = new Date();
time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/dd, E");
      if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 6);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(time);                             
    }
}
```

Holidays are not important so just excluding weekends I guess. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand adding five business days to current date is same as adding a week.

Try this:

```
   var time = new Date(+new Date + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
   time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/dd, E");
```